# The best way to test classes implementing the same interface

Tags: java, junit, junit4

So, for example I have a few classes implementing the `List<T>` interface. How to test them - whether they implement the methods correctly?

Now I only see one way to do so:

```
public class MyListImplementationsTest {
    private Collection<List<Integer>> listImplementations;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        listImplementations = Arrays.asList(
            new QuickList<Integer>(), new EfficientMemoryList<Integer>()
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsEmptyAfterCreationEmptyList() {
        // Use forEachList(handler) in order to not iterate
        // the lists manually every time.
        // May be there is no need to do so,
        // because using <<for (item : items)>> instead of
        // iterating using index prevents from OutOfBounds errors
        forEachList(new OnEachListHandler<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onEach(List<Integer> list) {
                assertTrue(list.isEmpty());
            }
        });
    }

    private <T> void forEachList(OnEachListHandler<T> handler) {
        for (List<T> each : listImplementations) {
            handler.onEach(each);
        }
    }

    private static interface OnEachListHandler<T> {
        void onEach(List<T> each);
    }
}
```

But in my opinion it's complicated to iterate lists in every test.

Is there more elegant way to test classes implementing the same interface in `JUnit4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a base test which can test anything of type `List<T>` plus an abstract method which creates such a list.

Then implement a test per list type which extends the base test. JUnit will run the test cases from the base class plus any that you define in the extension.

```
abstract class AbstractListTest<T> {
    protected abstract List<T> createList();

    @Test
    public void testIsEmpty() {
        List<T> list = createList();
        assertTrue(list.isEmpty());
    }

    ...more tests...
}

class QuickListTest extends AbstractListTest<QuickList> {
    protected QuickList createList() {
        return new QuickList();
    }
}
```

JUnit won't run the abstract base class but it will see the inherited tests and run all of them. You can also add new tests to `QuickListTest` or override ones from the base class.

Basically, JUnit will take the class, find all public `@Test` methods from the whole inheritance tree and run them.

Comment: But how can `JUnit` run the tests from the base class if it's abstract ?

Comment: Subclass the base class and implement an abstract factory method. JUnit will run the implemented methods on the superclass just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I will consider breaking up the tests for different list implementations into their respective test cases, so that they pass or fail independently.

Using your `.isEmpty()` as an example, if `QuickList.isEmpty()` and `EfficientMemoryList.isEmpty()` have different implementations i.e. different meaning for the concept of `empty`, then it makes sense for them to be tested independently. Currently, your `testIsEmptyAfterCreationEmptyList` will fail if 1 list implementation failed, but the others passed.

Otherwise, if `QuickList.isEmpty()` and `EfficientMemoryList.isEmpty()` share the same implementation, then you can consider moving the implementation to a common base class, and write tests for that base class.

Just because classes share the same interface, doesn't mean their tests need to be lumped and coupled.

Answer (score 0):

Create a test each implementation separatelly: `QuickListTest` and `EfficientMemoryListTest`.

### `QuickListTest.java`

```
public class QuickListTest extends ListBase {   
    @Test
    public void shouldBeEmpty() throws Exception {   
        assertThatIsEmpty(new QuickList<Integer>());   
    }    
}
```

### `BaseList.java`

```
public abstract class ListBase {    
    protected void assertThatIsEmpty(QuickList<Integer> actual) {
        assertThat(actual).isEmpty();
    }
}
```